# ListView Getting JsonArray php

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, for-loop

The problem is that i dont know how to view "username" from friend array:

This is the json i'm recieving from php:

```
08-30 16:44:08.485    
1619-2810/com.gcator E/JSON﹕
{"tag":null,
 "success":1,
 "error":0,
 "friend":{
  "username":"Kerrigan",
  "latitude":"52.75315",
  "longitude":"15.22528"
 }
}
 {
 "tag":null,
 "success":1,
 "error":0,
 "friend":{
   "username":"Zahary",
   "latitude":"52.72423",
   "longitude":"15.24610"
 }
}
```

as You see array is broken too. This is the case if php recieve tag "getfriends" from android. I need to get friends in one array "friend" this is the code:

```
case 'getfriends':

        $id = $_POST ['id'];
        $response = array();

        $user = $db->getUserById($id);
        if($user){
            $friends = $db->getFriendsByUser($user);
            if($friends){
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($friends) ; $i++) {
                    $locationf = $db->getLocationByUser($friends[$i]);
                    $latitude = $locationf->getLatitude();
                    $longitude = $locationf->getLongitude();
                    $name = $friends[$i]->getUsername();

                    $response = new $response;
                    $response["friend"]['username'] = $name;
                    $response["friend"]['latitude'] = $latitude;
                    $response["friend"]['longitude'] = $longitude;


                }
                $response["success"]= 1;
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                echo $response = "u dont have any Friends<br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "dupa";
            echo var_dump($friends);
        }
```

, then use this friend array in android to List "username".

I did Async task where json is recieved but i dont know how to make loop that  extract usernames of friends and put it do listviev, then on click will redirect to map activity

```
private class GetFriends extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>
{
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FriendList.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Searching Friends ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefID = getSharedPreferences("userId", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String ID = sharedPrefID.getString("KEY_ID", " dupa");


        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.getFriends(ID);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                String result = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                if(Integer.parseInt(result) == 1){
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading View");
                    pDialog.setTitle("Getting Friends");

                }else{

                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Labe.setText("There are no Friends :( Go to site make some !");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        pDialog.dismiss();


    }
}
```

Any ideas/help ? Thanks :) I've searched but there was no good answer for me.

Comment: please validate json response from http://jsonlint.com/ which you are getting and then modify your php file to get proper json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is syntax error in your Json..response should be like..

```
[
  {
    "tag":null,
    "success":1,
    "error":0,
    "friend":{
        "username":"Kerrigan",
        "latitude":"52.75315",
        "longitude":"15.22528"
    }
  },
  {
    "tag":null,
    "success":1,
    "error":0,
    "friend":{
        "username":"Zahary",
        "latitude":"52.72423",
        "longitude":"15.24610"
    }
  }
]
```

> Instead of passing json object pass whole json string to this method there  you can put your condition easily...
>   I have changed code below and added your condition...

Code onPost:

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String json){
   try {
    JSONObject root = new JSONObject(json);
    String result = root.getString("success");
    JSONArray user_array = root.getJSONArray("users");
        for (int i = 0; i < user_array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) user_array.getJSONObject(i);
              if(Integer.parseInt(result) == 1){
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading View");
                pDialog.setTitle("Getting Friends");
                String user = jsonObj.getString("username");
              }else{
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Labe.setText("There are no Friends :( Go to site make some !");
              }
        }
   }catch(JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

Comment: ok i ve got same thing like u posted here. Next problem is that after recieving this, logcat is vieving in one line this json.response, and next line :

`08-30 20:02:29.912    22511-766/com.gcator E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"success":1,"friend":{"username":"Szamus","latitude":"52.75315856933594","longitude":"15.225287437438965"}},{"success":1,"friend":{"username":"Zahariasz","latitude":"52.72423314689028","longitude":"15.246105194091797"}}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject` how to change it ?

Comment: are you getting "success" value correct? I have changed answer check it if it helps...

Comment: php return var is:
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 1, "error" => 0, "friend" => $respon );

returning valuse  in android debuger is :

Comment: sry i cant get used to this replier :D so,

php return var is:
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 1, "error" => 0, "friend" => $respon );

returning valuse  in android debuger is :

> {"tag":null,
 "success":1,
 "error":0,
 "friend":
  [{
   "username":"Szamus",
   "latitude":"52.75315856933594",
   "longitude":"15.225287437438965"
   },
   {
   "username":"Zahariasz",
   "latitude":"52.72423314689028",
   "longitude":"15.246105194091797"
  
  }]
  
} <

Comment: > Async task is like u wanted:
        onPost(JSONObject json) {
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    String result = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(result) == 1){
                      //  JSONArray friends = json.getJSONArray("friend");
                        JSONObject friend = json.getJSONObject("friend");
                        String username = friend.getString("username");
                        listt.setText(username);
                    }else{sth.}

Comment: and the problem is that after recieving data (succes:1) getting something like that:


> System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value [{"username":"Szamus","latitude":"52.75315856933594","longitude":"15.225287437438965"},{"username":"Zahariasz","latitude":"52.72423314689028","longitude":"15.246105194091797"}] at friend of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100) <

i Was tryinbg changing it to String , Array but nothing is working. Probably im doing something wrong with converting. I need this data to view in ListView...

Comment: Sorry my mistake...I took `JSONObject` as `JSONArray`..I changed the `onPost` code please have a look at it...if it works change/replace condition according to you..and yes I have test it..`"username"`,`"latitude"`,`"longitude"` value is returning....

Comment: 09-03 18:45:29.204  21891-22423/com.gcator E/JSON﹕ [{"success":1,"username":"Szamus"},{"success":1,"username":"Zahariasz"}]
09-03 18:45:29.204  21891-22423/com.gcator E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"success":1,"username":"Szamus"},{"success":1,"username":"Zahariasz"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject -.- i dont get it

Probably i fcked up with php because when i'll change in php one thing error looks like:

Comment: 09-03 18:48:52.895  21891-25156/com.gcator E/JSON﹕ {"success":1,"users":[{"username":"Szamus"},{"username":"Zahariasz"}]}
09-03 18:48:52.895  21891-21891/com.gcator W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class org.json.JSONObject
i 've deleted  long and lat, because those data were useless for me.

Comment: is this your final json..and you are parsing this json in android,right?

Comment: Yes this is the final json that im recieving from php and is showing in  androids logcat

Comment: You provided me to my own solution :) Thanks to You i understand Json little bit more ;)

Answer (score 0):

If Youre curious this is my solution ;) :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                String result = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if (Integer.parseInt(result) == 1) {
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading View");
                    pDialog.setTitle("Getting Friends");


                    //JSONArray root = new JSONArray(json);
                    JSONArray friend = json.getJSONArray("users");
                    List<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < friend.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject att = (JSONObject) friend.getJSONObject(i);

                        String res = att.getString("username");
                        item.add(res);



                    }



                    SharedPreferences FriendList = getSharedPreferences("FriendList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = FriendList.edit();
                    edit.putString("KEY_FRIENDS", item.toString());
                    edit.commit();
                } else {

                    pDialog.dismiss();

                }

            }else {

                pDialog.dismiss();

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        pDialog.dismiss();


    }
```

Its returning [Szamus,Zahariasz]
now i need to get this and put it into ListView -.-

Comment: I passed string to just show you how it works, well you can pass any thing (`JSONObject` or `String`) its your choice..`Happy Coding`:)